# Xamarin Android, List Adapter returns correct position in getView but wrong inside getView image click event

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin

I have a listview having height width both is "match-parent" which gets populated using adapter and the "position" which I am getting in getview is correct but viewholder.image.click event always give position according to visible area. Like if I change the listview height to some static dp then the visible area   increase to 4 element 0,1,2,3 after that it again show 0,1,2,3 which should be 5,6...

This problem resolve on creating the convertView every time which is actually a wrong approach.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        MyDealViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        View rowView = convertView;
        Toast.MakeText (baseActivity, string.Format (position.ToString ()), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        if (rowView == null)
        {
            rowView = baseActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DealListItem, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyDealViewHolder();
            viewHolder.LikeImage= rowView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgDealImage);
            viewHolder.LikeImage.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                Toast.MakeText (baseActivity, string.Format (position.ToString ()), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                viewHolder.LikeImage.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.heart_red_icon);
            };
            rowView.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder= (MyDealViewHolder)rowView.Tag;
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

Here both toast giving different position. First one is correct and second one is acc to visible area of listview

Thanks

Comment: you cant access items on a listview that are not visible on the user, why you want that?

Comment: @CDrosos - There is a image view for like /unlike. On clicking on unlike image it is changing to like image. On clicking on 1st element's unlike image I am setting a new image for like but the 3rd element(which is not  visible that time) image also get changed

Comment: @CDrosos - On clicking on 0th element which is in visible area its image get changes but when  scroll up the 3element image also got changed. As the position is 0 for the 1st element and the 3rd element (which is invisible)

Comment: try to add dynamically the rows on the view and control only the visible ones, i have done something similar here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29748/creating-a-layout-for-a-fragment-that-views-can-be-added-and-removed-dynamically#latest

Comment: @CDrosos What you said about *not being allowed to access items on a listview that are not visible to the user* could represent a big step ahead to the solution of my own question, which is somewhat similar to this one, could you please come check it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491960/how-to-retrieve-the-row-content-of-a-listview-item-when-user-clicks-on-it/36500578#36500578 ? Thanks a lot man!